# Reported speech word order

Tags: word-order, reported-speech

I need to convert the following to reported speech:

> in terms of availability of coming to Germany how much notice do you
>   need?

Which one is correct ?

- When he asked me what was my avaliability of coming  to Germany
- When he asked me what my avaliability of coming  to Germany was

Comment: They both sound awkward.  I would say "When he asked about my availability for coming to Germany..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second question  is the correct one.

```
 A direct question may start with a) an interrogative word/expression or, b) with an auxiliary.
 Ex a) **What** is your availability of coming to Germany? As you can see the subject "your availability of coming to Germany" comes after the main verb or, if you have an auxiliary accompanying the main verb, it comes in between.(Changing the tense- ex- What will  your availability of coming to Germany be?    
  But, what happens to this question if you place something before like "when he asked me..?- (in this case, to report something), - THE ORDER OF THE DIRECT QUESTION CHANGES AND, after the question word, immediately comes the subject and, AFTER IT, the verb(s),so
```

" when he asked me *WHAT* *my availability of coming to Germany* WAS..."(would be the correct one)

*The previous information refers directly to the question you are asking about but there is much more to learn about this topic,*

In case you are interested...(gladys_drust@hotmail.com)

Comment: I do not understand why the answer I wrote is not complete.